# Problema con variables de sesión entre distintos archivos .php

Tags: php, session

Tengo dos archivos 
archivo1.php que redirige a archivo2.php, en los dos esta session_start(); y hago print_r($_SESSION); en ambos pero solo se muestra en el archivo1.php, que podría estar mal?

Esto solo me sucede en el servidor, pues en local si funciona bien en ambos archivos.

**archivo1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$formatoId = $_SESSION['formatosession'];
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

**archivo2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$formatoId = $_SESSION['formatosession'];
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Este es el resultado del archivo1.php: Array ( [formatosession] => 39314 )

Este es el resultado del archivo2.php: Array ( )

Comment: Sin ver el código no podemos ayudarte. Y dinos qué tipo de servidor es, si gratuito, de pago, etc. Algunos servidores gratuitos tienen limitaciones. Pulsa en [edit]  para mejorar la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Hola, he actualizado mi consulta, ya he agregado el codigo. Y es un servidor de paga

Comment: ¿Pero, cómo pasas del `archivo1` al `archivo2`? Dices que haces redirecciones, pero no veo ningún código de redirección. No sabemos si antes de redirigir destruyes la sección o qué haces. Muestra el contexto completo, por favor.

Comment: <input type='button' value='Guardar' style='height:30px;width:150px; float:right;' onclick=\"www.sitio.com/archivo2.php';\"/>

Con este enlace hago cambio de archivo. ¿Se destruye la sesión al poner www.sitio.com al pasar de archivo?

Answer (score 0):

Así no te va a funcionar. Para redirigir desde el botón tienes que usar:

```
document.location.href
```

Y en la URL no tienes que poner `www.` etc, sino solamente el nombre del archivo

Por ejemplo:

## `archivo1.php`

```
<input type="button" value="Guardar" style="height:30px;width:150px; float:right;" onclick="document.location.href='archivo2.php'";/> 
<?php
    session_start();
    $formatoId = $_SESSION['formatosession']; // ¿ ?
    $_SESSION["a"]="hola A";
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

En `archivo1.php` no veías nada porque no estabas poniendo nada en la variable de sesión. En este ejemplo, cuando se abra el archivo verás esto en pantalla:

```
Array ( [a] => hola A )
```

## `archivo2.php`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["b"]="hola B";
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Cuando le des al botón en `archivo1.php` verás esto en pantalla al abrirse `archivo2.php`:

```
Array ( [a] => hola A [b] => hola B )
```